# Jquery If Statement - Toggle Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

```
                    $(document).ready(function() {

            $("span#label_Flat").hide();
            $("span#added_Flat").hide();
            $("span#removed_Flat").hide();



            if ($('#Flat:checked').val() != false) {

                $('#Flat').click(function() {
                    $("span#label_Flat").toggle();
                    $("span#removed_Flat").toggle();

                });

            } else {

                $('#Flat').click(function() {
                    $("span#label_Flat").toggle();
                    $("span#added_Flat").toggle();

            });                 
        });
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of why this isnt working?

I want to hide three span and only toggle two of them to be visible depending on if the checkbox is checked or not.

Currently, the span are not hidden, and therefore do not toggle between hide and show as they should.

The html is:

```
<input id="Flat" type="checkbox" name="Flat" checked />


<p>
<span id="label_Flat">Flat: </span>
<span id="added_Flat">Added</span>
<span id="removed_Flat">Removed</span>
</p>
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/WEq5u/10/

Comment: Can you post the HTML your using. It would help us answer the question a bit easier.

Comment: You forgot to mention what exactly is the problem; like, what does it do that it shouldn't, or what errors you get, or whatever.

Comment: I clarified some things and changed the code a bit to make it clearer. Also added the html. Apologies, and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this. To find whether the checkbox is checked, you can just use `this.checked` property which will return `true` if it is checked or else `false`.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("span#label_Flat").hide();
            $("span#mp_Flat").hide();
            $("span#removed_Flat").hide();

            $('#Flat').click(function() {
                if(this.checked){
                   $("span#label_Flat").toggle();
                   $("span#removed_Flat").toggle();
                }
                else{
                   $("span#label_Flat").toggle();
                   $("span#mp_Flat").toggle();
                }
            }).click();

        });
```

Comment: @Teeny - Try my edited answer now, I am calling the click handler on page load it will show/hide the spans on page load based on checkbox status.

Comment: @ ShankarSangoli still having the same issue, i cant seem to spot what is going wrong http://jsfiddle.net/WEq5u/8/

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in the fiddle. I modified it little take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WEq5u/12/

Comment: I hope thats what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, thankyou, its very very close to what I am looking for. I just need to hide the whole thing initially, and hide it again afterwards if the box is clicked by mistake. ill make some amendments. thanks so much.

Comment: I have made changes http://jsfiddle.net/WEq5u/16/ would you know how to stop Flat: Added from appearing if you uncheck then check again? I would prefer it if it became hidden again. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here, but I think

```
 if ($('#Flat:checked').val() != undefined) {
```

should be

```
 if ($('#Flat:checked').val() != false) {
```

checked val should return true or false, and undefined only if it isn't a check box as far as I know.

Comment: Doesnt solve my problem, but makes sense. I will add it in, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This should work , i've taken the code of ShankarSangoli and just added the case if the page loads with the checkbox checked or not.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("span#label_Flat").hide();
    $("span#mp_Flat").hide();
    $("span#removed_Flat").hide();

    if ($('#Flat').attr('checked') == true) {
        $("span#label_Flat").toggle();
        $("span#removed_Flat").toggle();
    }
    else {
        $("span#label_Flat").toggle();
        $("span#mp_Flat").toggle();
    }
    $('#Flat').click(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("span#label_Flat").toggle();
            $("span#removed_Flat").toggle();
        }
        else {
            $("span#label_Flat").toggle();
            $("span#mp_Flat").toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Edited the code in jsfiddle, still no success, but thank you.

Comment: your html is incorrect . <input id="Flat" type="checkbox" name="Flat" checked="checked" />

Comment: Make sure that u included Jquery library. http://jsfiddle.net/NBV8V/ i used ShankarSangoli code it's cleaner :)